# Derivation on equality

Tags: calculus, algorithms

I was reading about the upper bound running time of construction a binary heap in the following [article](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~meesh/351/mount/lectures/lect14-heapsort-analysis-part.pdf).

I am perplexed by the following approximation.

$T(n) = 2^{h} \sum_{j=0}^{h} j/2^{j}$ to $2^{h+1}$.

I specifically do not understand with the infinite geometric series argument.

Is it possible to take derivative on both side and substitute on any equality?

Comment: "Is it possible to take derivative on both side and substitute on any equality?" Within limits. Here, you can take a geometric series $\sum_0^\infty x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$, differentiate, $\sum_0^\infty k\cdot x^{k-1} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$, multiply with $x$, $\sum_0^\infty k\cdot x^k = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$ and insert $x = \frac12$ to obtain the approximation.

Comment: @DanielFischer. You should consider turning this into an answer.

Comment: Please justify the down vote with a comment so that it can be a learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to take derivative on both side and substitute on any equality?

Yes, often. Not quite always, but for geometric series, within the interval of convergence, you can. First you make the $\frac12$ a variable (consider the domain $0 \leqslant x < 1$),

$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^j = \frac{1}{1-x},$$

and differentiate,

$$\sum_{j=0}^h j\cdot x^{j-1} \leqslant \sum_{j=0}^\infty j\cdot x^{j-1} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.$$

The inequality holds obviously, since all summands are non-negative, and since we restricted to non-negative $x$, we can multiply the inequality with $x$,

$$\sum_{j=0}^h j\cdot x^j \leqslant \sum_{j=0}^\infty j\cdot x^j = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.$$

Now substitute the value $\frac12$ back in,

$$\sum_{j=0}^h j2^{-j} \leqslant \sum_{j=0}^\infty j 2^{-j} = \frac{1/2}{(1-1/2)^2} = 2,$$

and you have the used inequality. It works very directly here because all terms are non-negative. In the more general situation where some terms of the series are negative and others positive, establishing the inequality - if it holds at all - is less simple.